# How to fix my knowledge base?

Tags: prompt-design, llm, knowledge-base

I use Langchain.js with HNSWLib. I am building a chat bot for an automotive dealer.

here's is part of knowledge base .txt file I use as input to the model.

```
Q: Where is this inventory item/boat/RV/tractor, or the brand model located?
A: It is located in Florida.
```

When I query something like, "Where is this Cobia located?", the model outputs that it doesn't know, but it is clearly mentioned in my knowledge base text that its in Florida.

I am new to AI and whole GenAI world. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The questions:

1. "Where is this Cobia located?"
2. "Where is this inventory item/boat/RV/tractor, or the brand model located?"

are different, hence the model outputs that it doesn't know.

---

GPT 3.5 doesn't recognize Cobia as a brand name. From
https://chat.openai.com/share/b4c3d511-682e-45e2-9340-e22d66bf843f:

[image]

Comment: Well, Cobia is a brand name.. I explicitly stated brand name on the knowledge base. Do you have better idea than mine?  Sometimes model works but randomly.

Comment: @AdamS base.txt contains "Q: Where is this inventory item/boat/RV/tractor, or the brand model located?", where is Cobia stated in base.txt?

Comment: @AdamS Well, GPT must be intelligent enough to detect Cobia as a brand name. No?

Comment: @AdamS GPT 3.5 doesn't recognize Cobia as a brand name. From 
https://chat.openai.com/share/b4c3d511-682e-45e2-9340-e22d66bf843f: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4FFq.png

Comment: @AdamS Consider providing additional context about Cobia in as much detail as possible before asking your question. While the model may not retain this information for an extended period, it can enhance its understanding temporarily, aiding in generating a more informed response when you ask the question again. If the model lacks knowledge on the subject, feel free to inform it accordingly and then ask.